# Counting dict elements in subarray yields unexpected number

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I am counting the elements in a subarray in a json file to avoid an 'IndexError: list index out of range' but the number of elements is > what I expect.

Adding test code print(diclen);print(dic) gives me a value > what I except (8 instances of propValue), output:

12

{'propConceptGroup': {'propConcept': [{'propCategory': 'NAMES', 'propName': 'RxNorm Name', 'propValue': 'lercanidipine'}, {'propCategory': 'CODES', 'propName': 'RxCUI', 'propValue': '135056'}, {'propCategory': 'CODES', 'propName': 'UMLSCUI', 'propValue': 'C0526399'}, {'propCategory': 'CODES', 'propName': 'ATC', 'propValue': 'C08CA13'}, {'propCategory': 'CODES', 'propName': 'DRUGBANK', 'propValue': 'DB00528'}, {'propCategory': 'CODES', 'propName': 'MESH', 'propValue': 'C060343'}, {'propCategory': 'CODES', 'propName': 'SNOMEDCT', 'propValue': '356862006'}, {'propCategory': 'CODES', 'propName': 'SNOMEDCT', 'propValue': '395986007'}]}}

```
def getdrugbank(rx):
    urlroot = 'https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/'
    urlend = '/allProperties.json?prop=names+codes'
    url = urlroot + rx + urlend
    response = requests.get(url)
    dic = response.json()
    i=0; drugbank = "NA"
    if dic == {"propConceptGroup":None}:
        drugbank = "NA"
    else:
        diclen = len(dic['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'][0]['propValue'])-1
        print(diclen);print(dic)
        for i in range(0,diclen):
            if dic['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'][i]['propName'] == "DRUGBANK":    
                drugbank = dic['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'][i]['propValue']
    return drugbank
```

Answer (score 0):

`len(dic['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'][0]['propValue'])` that will evaluate to the length of the value of `dic['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'][0]['propValue']`, so you are calculating the length of `propValue` strings such as `DB00528`.

What you nee is to know the number of elements in the array which you get with ust `len(dic['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'])`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply @Anler

i discovered the problem was with my indexing and
len(dic['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'][0]['propValue']) yields the length of the 'propValue' string and NOT an array, I was expecting a subarray

building on that, i ditched len() and rewrote the code to cycle through the dict subarray checking for a key propName (for value propValue) and 'getting' the values I'm seeking using [i][0]['propName']

```
for i in dic['propConceptGroup']['propConcept']:
            if [i][0]['propName'] == "DRUGBANK":
                print([i][0]['propValue'])
                drugbank = [i][0]['propValue']
                break
            elif [i][0]['propName'] == "SPL_SET_ID":
                break
```